# Tem alguma maneira de pesquisar minhas perguntas, resposta e favoritos?

Tags: debate, novo-recurso

Muitas vezes sinto falta desse tipo de pesquisa tanto aqui quanto no `so-en`, favorito muitas respostas para futuras consultas e depois para encontrar é bastante trabalhoso.

Comment: [Organização dos favoritos](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/4940/91)

Comment: **Relacionado:** http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/5551/3635, http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2602/3635 (essa é boa para encontrar coisas para responder) e http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/5619/3635

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Obviamente tem a [página com todos favoritos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/7704/rubstackoverflow?tab=favorites).

Suas perguntas e respostas pode pesquisar normal só indicando que quer filtrar pelo seu ID: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A7704.

na página de busca tem um *link* do lado direito com as opções avançadas. Lá tem todos os filtros que pode usar, inclusive se quer só perguntas ou só respostas:

```
tags
    [tag]
exato
    "palavras aqui"
autor
    user:1234
    user:me (seu)
pontos
    score:3 (3+)
    score:0 (nenhum)
respostas
    answers:3 (3+)
    answers:0 (nenhum)
    isaccepted:yes
    hasaccepted:no
    inquestion:1234
visitas
    views:250
seções
    title:apples
    body:"maçãs laranjas"
url
    url:"*.example.com"
favoritos
    infavorites:mine
    infavorites:1234
status
    closed:yes
    duplicate:no
    migrated:no
    wiki:no
    deleted:no
tipos
    is:question
    is:answer
Excluir
    -[tag]
    -apples
```

Mais informação na [página de ajuda sobre pesquisa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/searching).

Comment: Para ressaltar `infavorites:mine` seria nos seus favoritos, `infavorites:<ID>` seria para pesquisar os favoritos de outra pessoa, por exemplo os favoritos do bigown no meta: [infavorites:101](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=infavorites%3A101)

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento é verdade, nem tinha lido :)

Answer (score 3):

Eu costumo usar o recurso do Google. Utilizo tanto que o browser até auto completa.

> site:pt.stackoverflow.com [nome do usuario] [palavras chave para
>   busca]

Muitas vezes é mais eficiente que a própria busca dentro do site.

Particularmente acho muito mais prático para a maioria dos casos.

Mas, por favor, não estou a falar mal do site. É apenas uma dica de como obter mais resultados de forma alternativa.

Além do mais é até benéfico para o site pois aumenta o valor dos links no rankeamento do Google.